# Exporting to multiple worksheets via crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I'm creating a crystal report which would use two stored procedures. My requirement is to have the data from stored procedures spit into two worksheet.
 Is that possible in boxi crystal report?
 Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crystal Reports Excel export with worksheets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947687/crystal-reports-excel-export-with-worksheets)

Answer (score 1):

When you say Worksheet, do you mean Excel?

I see there's is a possible answer here:

[Crystal Reports Excel export with worksheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947687/crystal-reports-excel-export-with-worksheets)